# How to unlock the branch in clearcase

Tags: branch, clearcase

There is one branch and it is locked by other user.
I need to unlock that branch for doing check-in and check-out.

I tried to do it from UI but it is not allowing.
What option do I have to unlock that branch?

I am having the Administrative rights but still getting the error:

```
Unable to unlock the 'brtype:-----@\-----
No permission to perform operation "unlock"
Must be one of "Object Owner, VOB owner, member of cc group".
Unable to unlock branch type : "-------"
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal command is [cleartool unlock](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_unlock.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-2-1-20):

```
cleartool unlock brtype:aBranch@\aVob
```

That would be using a branch-type-selector (brtype:type-name[@vob-selector]).
You can check if it is locked with a:

```
cleartool lslock brtype:aBranch@\aVob
```

However, it does mention (in [`cleartool lock`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lock.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-2-1-4)):

> #### Restriction for locking/unlocking a branch:
>
> - Unix: Branch creator, element owner, VOB owner, root
> - Branch creator, element owner, VOB owner, member of the ClearCase administrators group

If the owner of that branch cannot unlock it, you need to ask to your ClearCase admin.

Comment: @Navee It is is not an option, but a branch type selector (I have edited the answer)

Comment: thanx VonC I have checked with the command what you have given and it is showing the locked details. But how to unlock that branch?

Comment: @Navee my answer points out the condition for you to be able to unlock it. But if you do not meet those condition, you either need to contact the branch owner, or the ClearCase admin (since you clearly do *not* have admin right).

Comment: when i am trying to unlock the branch from command line it is saying that "Object is not locked, Unable to unlock branch" I am confused now. By using "cleartool lslock brtype:aBranch@\aVob" command I am able to see that there is lock on branch but while using cleartool unlock command it says there is no lock on branch. What is the problem here?

Comment: @Navee can you copy the output of the lslock? And what exact command are you using for the unlock?

Comment: the lslock command is cleartool> lslock brtype:sdm.2.1\sdm and the output is like 2014-06-12 sjohn lock branch type "sdm.2.1"<locked> "Locked for all users". And the unlock command is cleartool>unlock D:\view\sjohn_latest\sdm.@@/main/sdm.2.1 and the output is like cleartool:Error: Object is not locked. Cleartool:Error:Unable to unlock branch "D:\view\sjohn_latest\sdm\.@@main\sdm.2.1".

Comment: @Navee that is expected: you are trying to unlock a branch for an element, instead of the branch type itself. To unlock the brtype, see my answer. `cleartool unlock brtype:sdm.2.1@\sdm`

Comment: Thax Vonc i tried with the command what you gave and that is correct but i have some problem with the permission.

Comment: @Navee Hence my suggestion to contact your ClearCase admin.